# Are JavaScript template literals guaranteed to call toString()?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, tostring, template-literals

```
const num = 42
const str = `My number is ${num}`
```

In this code what guarantee do I have about the conversion of `num` to a `string` ?

Is it guaranteed to just call its `toString()` method or could the conversion be done in another way ?

Comment: The conversion is always done by `String(num)`. That *might* call `.toString()` or it might not, there are many ways.

Comment: @Bergi plz write an answer if you have the info for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Untagged templates use the ECMAScript `ToString()` abstract operation. The logic of template literal evaluation is spread over several sections which makes it difficult to follow, so I'll just post a link to it: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-evaluation

[`ToString(argument)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) uses a table instead of algorithmic steps, so I'll write out some pseudocode here:

```js
switch (Type(argument)) {
  case 'Undefined':
    return 'undefined';
  case 'Null':
    return 'null';
  case 'Boolean':
    return argument ? 'true' : 'false';
  case 'Number':
    return Number::toString(argument);
  case 'String':
    return argument;
  case 'Symbol':
    throw new TypeError();
  case 'BigInt':
    return BigInt::toString(arugment);
  case 'Object':
    return ToString(ToPrimitive(argument, 'string'));
}
```

As you can see, no js execution happens at all for primitive values, the engine internally creates a string representation. For objects, we go into the `ToPrimitive()` algorithm.

[`ToPrimitive(input, PreferredType)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) will try to get the `Symbol.toPrimitive` method from `input`, and if it's present, call it with the given `PreferredType` hint. If `input` does not have a `Symbol.toPrimitive` property, it falls back to `OrdinaryToPrimitive`.

[`OrdinrayToPrimitive(O, hint)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) will try to call the `toString` and `valueOf` methods. If `hint` is `'string'`, it try to call `toString` method first, otherwise it will try to call the `valueOf` method first. If either of those methods are present and they don't return an object, their return value will be used. If neither are present or they both return objects, a TypeError will be thrown.

So to answer your original question, converting `42` will not call any other methods. The engine will internally create a string representation (`'42'`), and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If either value is not a string, it’ll be converted to a string using the usual rules. For example, if action is an object, its .toString() method will be called.

Read the full article from mozilla
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/

Comment: don't forget about tagged templates - it may not!

Comment: Any official source for this affirmation, like an ECMAScript spec chapter ?
The article seems more like a blog post

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a function of `Object` Primitive as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Edit:
ECMA specification is `expression` as described [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-SubstitutionTemplate).

Again in [MDN - Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is written:

*The default function just concatenates the parts into a single string*

Comment: Sure it is, but who says it is going to be called in template literals ?

Comment: @Drax I added more details

Comment: This is not the question, the question is not about the concatenation, the question is about parts that are not string, like a number for example, how do we know it is converted with the `toString()` method and not in another way ?